# cts: index-order in cts:element-values?

Tags: xquery, marklogic-10, cts

I want to pick the ID from the lasted doc based on DATE, but when I am using the below query I am getting an error:

```
cts:element-values(xs:QName('ID'),(),(),
  cts:and-query((
    cts:element-value-query(xs:QName('TEST'),'1')
  )),
  cts:index-order(cts:element-reference(xs:QName('DATE'),'descending'))
)
```

Comment: It isn't super helpful to say that you get an error and then not provide information about the error. What does it say? If you provide the error message, then people are more likely to be able to help you. That being said, it is likely that you don't have a range-index on the DATE element, so it can't sort your results by it.